# What do the 'normalize' parameters mean in sklearns confusion_matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am using sklearns `confusion_matrix` package to plot the results coupled with the accuracy, recall and precision score etc  and the graph renders as it should. However I am slightly confused by what the different values for what the `normalize` parameter mean. Why do we do it and what are the differences between the 3 options? As quoting from their documentation:

```
normalize{‘true’, ‘pred’, ‘all’}, default=None
Normalizes confusion matrix over the true (rows), predicted (columns) conditions or all the population. 
If None, confusion matrix will not be normalized.
```

Does it normalize the points to a percentage format to make it easily visually if datasets are too large? Or am I missing the point all together here. I have searched but the questions all appear to be stating how to do it, rather than the meaning behind them.

Answer (score 2):

A normalized version makes it easier to visually interpret how the labels are being predicted and also to perform comparisons. You can also pass `values_format= '.0%'` to display the values as percentages. The `normalize` parameter specifies what the denominator should be

- 'true': sum of rows (True label)
- 'pred': sum of columns (Predicted label)
- 'all': sum of all

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Generate some example data
X, y = make_moons(noise=0.3, random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=10)

# Train the classifier
clf = LogisticRegression()

clf.fit(X, y)

plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, y_test); plt.title("Not normalized");
plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, y_test, values_format= '.0%', normalize='true'); plt.title("normalize='true'");
plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, y_test, values_format= '.0%', normalize='pred'); plt.title("normalize='pred'");
plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, y_test, values_format= '.0%', normalize='all'); plt.title("normalize='all'");
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: So `pred` would show you the frequency of each square according to how many were true?

Comment: Right. In the example above, would be 6 for Class 0 and 4 for Class 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can think of it as a percentage. The default is to just show the absolute count value in each cell of the confusion matrix, i.e. how often each combination of true and predicted category levels occurrs.

But if you choose e.g. `normalize='all'`, every count value will be divided by the sum of all count values, so that you have relative frequencies whose sum over the whole matrix is 1. Similarly, if you pick `normalize='true'`, you will have relative frequencies per row.

Comment: Okay, I understand your first point just fine. I'm still trying to understand the latter. So if we assume an example of the sum of all count values being equal to 10,000. And the number of predicted `1` and true label `1` is equal to 400, then when `normalize = 'all'`, that respective value in the confusion matrix will be equal 4?

Comment: @Johnny Yes, it would be 4%.

Answer (score 1):

If you repeat an experiment with different sample sizes, you may want to compare confusion matrices across experiments. To do so, you wouldn't want to see the total counts for each matrix. Instead, you would want to see the counts normalized but you need to decide if you want terms normalized by total number of samples ("all"), predicted class counts ("pred"), or true class counts ("true"). For example:

```
In [30]: yt
Out[30]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])

In [31]: yp
Out[31]: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])

In [32]: confusion_matrix(yt, yp)
Out[32]:
array([[4, 3],
       [3, 0]])

In [33]: confusion_matrix(yt, yp, normalize='pred')
Out[33]:
array([[0.57142857, 1.        ],
       [0.42857143, 0.        ]])

In [34]: confusion_matrix(yt, yp, normalize='true')
Out[34]:
array([[0.57142857, 0.42857143],
       [1.        , 0.        ]])

In [35]: confusion_matrix(yt, yp, normalize='all')
Out[35]:
array([[0.4, 0.3],
       [0.3, 0. ]])
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a working example. I can understand now that normalising brings everything down to a shared scale now. But could you elaborate on the differences between the different parameters?

Comment: It just boils down to whether you want to know the percentages by total number of observations or broken down by class. And if you want them broken down by class, do you want them with respect to the predicted class counts (columns) or true class counts (rows). So if, for example, you had three classes (dogs, cats, and fish), you could easily answer questions like "What percentage of dogs get misclassified as cats?". In that case, you would want to normalize by "true" and you would look across the "dog" row for the "cat" column.